# CSRF token missing when sending valid csrf token

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf-protection

I am getting csrfTokenMissingException even when i am sending valid csrf token when submitting a spring form.
The scenario is when i restart application server and click on particular "abc" link immediately, it is throwing csrfTokenMissingException, but when I click on other link(xyz link) where csrf token is valid and it work properly, after that i click on abc link, then it works properly. In all the scenario I am sending valid csrf token.

```
<form id="menuForm" action="/TEST/loginValidate" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="_c`enter code here`srf" value="0179ad01-85d2-4587-b754-b1aa33243967">
</div>
</form>

function test(){

$('#menuForm').attr('action','testUrl');
$('#menuForm').submit();

}
```

---

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (accessDeniedException instanceof MissingCsrfTokenException
                || accessDeniedException instanceof InvalidCsrfTokenException) {

            System.out.println("  == :: accessDeniedException exception ---------------------  46464646  "+accessDeniedException.getClass());
            System.out.println(" == :: getRequestURI  "+request.getRequestURI());
            System.out.println(" ------ X-CSRF-Token "+request.getHeader("X-CSRF-Token"));

            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());

        }

        super.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);

    }
}
```

pls check code for reference.

Comment: Did you refresh the browser after restarting your server?

Comment: @Magnus after restarting the server. I have refreshed it and again logged into project and after that i click on link where i need to validate csrf token.

Comment: I think you're going to need to show some code if anyone is going to be able to help you. Try to construct a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that demonstrates your issue, then edit your question to include the code from that. You might well find that in doing so you discover the cause of the problem yourself.